# Indirect object pronouns

Tags: pronombres

I'm going through a grammar book and there is a scentence:

> A Daniel le gustan las peliculas romanticas.

Question:
Why is the indirect object pronoun 'le' used here?
Isn't there just a subject = Daniel, a verb = to like and a direct object = romantic movies

So wouldn't be correct to simply say this:

> A Daniel gustan las peliculas romanticas.

(without the 'le')

Comment: No, because the subject of gustar = romantic movies, not Daniel (indicated by the use of *gustan*, 3rd person plural). See eg https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/28754/how-do-verbs-like-gustar-actually-function and https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39608/me-va-a-gustar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A Daniel gustan las películas románticas". Sería una oración gramaticalmente mal construida.

**A Daniel**, no es el sujeto, sería **Objeto Indirecto** (**OI**).

---

"A Daniel **le** gustan las películas románticas"

**Los Pronombres de Objeto Indirecto.**

---

**Reglas Básicas**

Para no repetir el nombre de una persona o cosa se sustituyen los complementos por los pronombres, en este caso de **objeto indirecto**.

Existen seis formas diferentes para los pronombres de objeto indirecto, una para cada persona verbal. Así tenemos:

- Yo -> me
- Tú -> te
- Él / ella / usted -> **le**
- Nosotros / nosotras -> nos
- Vosotros / vosotras -> os
- Ellos / ellas / ustedes -> **les**

---

*Como excepción usamos "le" como pronombre de objeto directo masculino singular, pero no así para el femenino ni "les" para plural*.

---

Es habitual confundir los **OD** (Objeto Directo) como el **OI** (Objeto Indirecto), cuando las personas llevan delante la preposición "**a**".

Normalmente para saber si es un objeto directo hay que hacer la pregunta al ver verbo **¿qué?** y para saber si es un OI se realiza al verbo la pregunta **¿a quién?** / ¿qué?.

Los verbos de tipo "**gustar**" como son "encantar, interesar, importar, molestar, caer bien / mal, quedar bien / mal, divertir..." la persona no participa de forma activa en la acción, ya que lo que percibe es la sensación causada de aquello que se desea expresar.

- A Daniel le gustan las películas románticas.

Estos verbos incorporan el **objeto indirecto** en la estructura básica de la oración. Daniel, cuyo papel es pasivo, es el objeto indirecto, ya que lo que causa esa sensación que Daniel experimenta, son **las películas románticas**, que en este caso harían de sujeto.

- **A Daniel le** gustan las películas románticas.

¿A quién le gustan?. A Daniel, **objeto indirecto** y como es tercera persona de masculino singular entonces es "**Le gustan**".

---

**Otros ejemplos**

- He comprado una bici para Isabel.

¿A quién he comprado? A Isabel. Así "para Isabel" es el objeto indirecto y, como es tercera persona femenino singular, entonces decimos "**Le** he comprado una bici".

- Canta una canción a los peques

Canta (tú) una canción a los peques. ("peques", niños pequeños)

¿A quién canto? A los peques. Así "los peques" es el objeto indirecto, y como es tercera persona masculino plural, entonces decimos "Canta**les** una canción".

---

---

""A Daniel gustan las películas románticas"" It would be a grammatically poorly constructed sentence.

**To Daniel**, he is not the subject, it would be **Indirect Object** (**OI**).

---

"A Daniel **le** gustan las películas románticas"

**The Indirect Object Pronouns.**

---

**Basic rules**

In order not to repeat the name of a person or thing, complements are replaced by pronouns, in this case **indirect object**.

There are six different forms for indirect object pronouns, one for each verbal person. So we have:

- I -> me
- you -> te
- He / she / you -> **le**
- We / Nosotros/as -> nos
- You / Vosotros/as -> os
- They / Ellos/as -> **les**

---

*As an exception we use "le" as a masculine singular direct object pronoun, but not for the feminine nor "les" for the plural*.

---

It is common to confuse the **OD** (Direct Object) as the **OI** (Indirect Object), when people have the preposition "**a**" in front of them.

Normally, to know if it is a direct object, you have to ask the question when seeing the verb, **what**? and to know if it is an IO, the verb asks the question: to **whom**? / what?.

Verbs of the "gustar"(like), type such as "enchant, interest, import, annoy, like / not like, look good / not like, have fun..." the person does not actively participate in the action, since what he perceives is the sensation caused by what you want to express.

- A Daniel le gustan las películas románticas. (Daniel likes romantic movies).

These verbs incorporate the **indirect object** in the basic structure of the sentence. Daniel, whose role is passive, is the indirect object, since what Daniel experiences is caused by **romantic movies**, which in this case would act as the subject.

- - **A Daniel le** gustan las películas románticas. (**Daniel likes** romantic movies).

Who likes them? To Daniel, ** indirect object ** and since he is third person masculine singular then he is  "**Le gustan**" "He likes them".

---

**Other examples**

- He comprado una bici para Isabel. (I bought a bike for Isabel).

¿A quién he comprado? A Isabel. (Who have I bought? to Isabel). Thus "para Isabel" is the indirect object and, since she is the third person feminine singular, then we say  "**Le** he comprado una bici", "**I have bought a bike for her".

- Canta una canción a los peques. (Sing a song to the peques)

Canta (tu) una canción a los peques. (Sing (you) a song to the peques). ("peques", little children)

"¿A quien canto? (Who do I sing to?) To the peques So "the peques" is the indirect object, and since it is the third person masculine plural, then we say "Canta**le** una canción" (Sing a song to them).